# In pentaho dashboard how to display the table component columns using different sql datasources

Tags: components, datasource, pentaho

I want to display a table with data coming from different sql tables, like for a single table component, some columns of the table come from one sql query and other column from next query. Using join queries or sub queries will display wrong data. In table component there is only one option for selecting the data-source. 
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How will you keep rows of the table together when the columns can have more or less rows independently? If you can define a field that identifies the row, you have your join condition. If there's really nothing that makes a row a row, use separate table components and remove the spacing between them.

Comment: Oh yeah, I can try that..but how to pass the first table component value to the next component.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand that comment. Why do you need to pass values between table components? All should be controlled by the same parameters.

Comment: For example, three tables showing some amount, forth table i want to sum up all three table amount.

Comment: That really should be in one datasource/query. Perhaps we can help figure out how to join your different tables?

Comment: I did it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with Pentaho Data Integration/Kettle/Spoon and then you can pass the results to the table component, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript, in the pre-Execution function of the table component, you can change the datasource, but not for single columns.
You can hide some columns in the table component if you want.

**How to change the datasource with Javascript**

I created a Simple Parameter: refresh_table, and it contains the datasource of the table: sql_Empty, to show an empty table.
I created some Select components and when you choose a value and then you click on the Button component (a search button), the search button changes the value in the simple parameter 'refresh_table' with a new datasource based on the value in the select component: sql_A, sql_B.

```
function a() {
    var a = this.dashboard.getParameterValue('selectA');
    var b = this.dashboard.getParameterValue('selectB');

    if (a === 'ciao' && b === 'ciao') {
        this.dashboard.fireChange('refresh_table', 'sql_A');
    } else {
        this.dashboard.fireChange('refresh_table', 'sql_B');
    }
}
```

In the preExecution function of the table component, I wrote this function to change the datasource based on the parameter value of refresh_table.

```
function b() {
    this.chartDefinition.dataSource = this.dashboard.getParameterValue('refresh_table');
}
```